# Is there a way to find existing filters on a table in google sheet via apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet table with some filters. I need to unhide the filtered rows and run a script and re hide the rows with the same filters as there were.

I have tried to google but I have had no luck. any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
A rookie

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need something like this:

```
function main() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
  // get fiters and store them in array
  const critera_array = get_and_remove_filters(sheet);

  // do stuff

  // set filters back from the array
  set_filters(sheet, critera_array);  
}

function get_and_remove_filters(sheet) {
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const criteria1 = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(1);
  const criteria2 = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(2);
  sheet.getFilter().remove();
  return [criteria1, criteria2];
}

function set_filters(sheet, criteria) {
  sheet.getDataRange().createFilter();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria[0]);
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria[1]);
}
```

It will remove and restore the filters for first two columns. Likely there is a way to handle all columns.

Comment: Thanks this helped but it makes the sheet really slow as I added 14 column criteria.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. A see no way to make it faster. But probably someone does.